# Laravel asset not loading image from url

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I have used asset all the time for other projects and it works fine.
I have already executed the php artisan storage:link command.

I try:

```
<img src="{{ asset("/img/placerholder.jpg") }}">
```

This creates the path:

```
http://dev.backend.local/img/placerholder.jpg
```

Doesnt load the image, at the bottom I have:

```
<script src="{{ asset('/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/adminlte.js') }}"></script>
```

All of these work fine!

I have printed the fileperms of the jpg file it prints:

```
"rrw-rw-rw-"
33206
```

The plugins folder fileperms prints:

```
"drwxrwxrwx"
16895
```

Apache access log prints:

```
"GET /img/placerholder.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Comment: Where the file located?

Comment: It should be `<img src="{{ asset("storage/img/placerholder.jpg") }}">`

Comment: use single quote instead of double, change `<img src="{{ asset("/img/placerholder.jpg") }}">` to `<img src="{{ asset('/img/placerholder.jpg') }}">`